# How to share data or computations among training samples

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow2.0

I need to train a classifier, that should be based on 3 things: features of an object itself, some kind of context image representing its state relative to other objects, and a sequence of images representing even more context, but somewhat globally. The number of objects varies between images.

As for the neural network:
- the first input has a shape of `(batch_size, n)`, where `n` is the number of objects features (`n`~15);
- the second input has roughly a shape of `(batch_size, image_size, image_size, n)`, where `image_size` is the size of an image (`image_size` ~ 15);
- the shape of the third input, as you might guess, is `(batch_size, seq_len, image_size, image_size, n)`, where `seq_len` is sequence length (`seq_len` ~ 10).

When the number of training samples is relatively small, this is feasible. But when the number exceeds 100k examples, it already takes 12GB of memory. And that's too much since I need to feed even more. Things are going to be even worse when I will need to train something similar, but now for each pair of objects on the image.

But the thing is, that most of the data does not change between samples. If some image has 15 objects, then only the first and the second inputs will be different for those 15 objects, while the biggest one (the third) will remain the same. The computations needed for all the inputs are the same.

Despite my specific problem, it raises the general question if I can feed the third input only as many times as needed and perform the same computations for different samples?

P.S:
1) I would highly appreciate a better question formulation: I don't know if there is something out there and if that something has a name;
2) I do know about the existence of `tf.data`. But I can't seem to find any examples answering my question.

Comment: Why not PyTorch for your custom problem? It's basically Python in comparison to Tensorflow.